# error creating registry

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

My vb.net program creates/opens/edit Registry files. After development, when I use the program to another computer it returns an error:

[image: Error]

If I import the registry file to the computer, the program runs OK, so I guess the error has something to do with the creation of the registry file.

This is how the program creates registry file:

```
Function createRegistrykey()
    Dim openKey As RegistryKey
    openKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\RobinsonsRetailGroup\LogSettings", True)

    '[SPECIFICATION]
    If (openKey.GetValue("STORENAME") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("STORENAME", "RRR", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("STORENUMBER") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("STORENUMBER", "000", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If

    '[DEFAULT]
    If (openKey.GetValue("UTILFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("UTILFLR", "C:\Util", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("GRSFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("GRSFLR", "D:\DC\Instances\", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("EXPORTFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("EXPORTFLR", "C:\Export", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("OFFICEIMPFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("OFFICEIMPFLR", "C:\Program Files\", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("PCMSTBAKFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("PCMSTBAKFLR", "C:\BAK", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("DBASEBAKFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("DBASEBAKFLR", "D:\Backup\Store", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("INTBACKUPFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("INTBACKUPFLR", "D:\BACKUP", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("EXTBACKUPFLR") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("EXTBACKUPFLR", "none", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If

    '[POS]
    If (openKey.GetValue("POSUSER") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("POSUSER", "Administrator", RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
    If (openKey.GetValue("POSPASS") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("POSPASS", hashEncoding("isd"), RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If

    If (openKey.GetValue("LOGVIEWERPASS") = Nothing) Then
        openKey.SetValue("LOGVIEWERPASS", hashEncoding("BBOEY"), RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If

    openKey.Close()
    Return vbNull
End Function
```

Anyone knows why this error occurs?

Comment: Does SOFTWARE\RobinsonsRetailGroup\LogSettings key exist on that computer?

Comment: No, not yet. In my development machine, the program creates key if not yet created, but on the workstation where the program is supposed to be deployed returns the error above and does not create any key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN, about [RegistryKey.OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/xthy8s8d) Method:

> If the requested key does not exist, this method returns null instead of throwing an exception.

The `Null reference exception` you have on workstations where the key does not exist (which happens on the first call of `GetValue` from the (null) registryKey object) is totaly normal.

```
'[SPECIFICATION]
    If (openKey.GetValue("S...
```

So before to do anything with the key, you should test if it is null.

```
Dim openKey As RegistryKey
    openKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\RobinsonsRetailGroup\LogSettings", True)

If openKey IsNot Nothing
 (...)
Else
 (...)
End if
```

**And if you want to create the key if it doesn't exist, you should use instead the [RegistryKey.CreateSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method** that will create the key or open it for write access if already exists.

```
Dim openKey As RegistryKey
    openKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\RobinsonsRetailGroup\LogSettings")
```

Hope this helps.